# Handling images in relation to shape

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image, responsive

What I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TBKt.jpg
(don't mind the weirdly-clipped pictures, they are just placeholders)

What I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh29H.jpg

I need to place the circles with images directly into circles of SVG background (I put png in snippet for ease of use).
I tried: recreating the shape in CSS, putting SVG as an image into a container and using translate() with %, putting SVG as a background-img of a parent container and adding child-divs. None of the options are remotely responsive. I don't aim to have that option on the mobile view, but I need it responsive on desktop viewing. How do I place those images in relation to the div? Is HTML canvas the last and only option there?

```css
.red {
  background-color: var(--red);
}

.white {
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.yellow {
  background-color: rgb(207, 159, 0);
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.paint-drip {
  background-color: var(--white);
  margin-top: -6.25rem;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 38rem;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/5U286gO.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 99%, 0 99%); */
}

.p-nest-1 {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.p-nest-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 44%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 2vw solid var(--white);
}

.p-nest-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 58%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 2vw solid var(--white);
}
```

```html
<div class="paint-container mt-0">
  <div class="paint-drip">
    <div class="p-nest-1 circle yellow "></div>
    <div class="p-nest-2 circle yellow"></div>
    <div class="p-nest-3 circle yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want always the whole width of the image to appear - whatever the viewport dimensions? Start from that and measure everything else in terms of % width of the image. You can't bounce between vw and rem and hope to get things aligned correctly.

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying. I'll try with media queries, thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn’t mean you to use media queries, I can’t see how they would help. Look at using %s.